# How to find containing Polygon within a shapely MultiPolygon

Tags: python, shapely

In shapely, a MultiPolygon is made of several disjoint Polygons (except one-point intersections). If I have a MultiPolygon `polys` and a Point `pt`, then I can test for containment by

```
polys.contains(pt)
```

which gives `True` in case the point is in at least one of the polygons. I assume this is working efficiently on the inside by using some R-Tree. However, actually, I am interested, in *which* of the Polygons in the MultiPolygon the Point is contained. I wonder, whether there is a trick to identify it without testing through the list of polygons (i.e., `polys.geoms`)?

Any hint is appreciated - thanks already!!

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the syntax

```
for poly in polys.geoms:
    if poly.contains(pt):
        print(poly)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This is of course true - I was just wondering whether I can easily exploit the underlying R-Tree search for the MultiPolygon (if there is any - frankly, I didn't test performance differences or digged into the source to see, what is happening exactly).